# Program for ARP scanning

Tags: python, python-3.4

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#Fazer arping da conexao

import sys
from datetime import datetime
from scapy.all import *

try:
    interface = input ("\n[*] Set interface: ")
    ips = input("[*] Set IP RANGE or Network: ")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("\n user aborted")
    sys.exit()

print("Scanning...")
start_time = datetime.now()

conf.verb = 0

ans,unans = srp(Ether(dst = "ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/ARP(pdst = ips), timeout = 2, iface = interface ,inter= 0.1)

print("\n\tMAC\t\tIP\n")

for snd,rcv in ans:
    print(rcv.sprintf("%Ether.src% - %ARP.psrc%"))

stop_time = datetime.now()
total_time = stop_time - start_time
print("\n[*] Scan Completed")
print("[*] Scan Duration: %s" %(total_time))
```

I found this code on internet and I am trying to understand it.
I didnt understand :

```
 ans,unans = srp(Ether(dst = "ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/ARP(pdst = ips), timeout = 2, iface = interface ,inter= 0.1)
```

Why there is a tuple `ans,unans` ?
Whats is `inter= 0.1` ?

```
for snd,rcv in ans:
        print(rcv.sprintf("%Ether.src% - %ARP.psrc%"))
```

I didnt understand `rcv.sprintf`. What is this? Why rcv.sprintf instead of print?
What is `conf.verb = 0` ?

Could someone explain it?

Comment: These questions can be easily answered by just looking up the documentation. Have a look here: http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html

Comment: I did not find conf.verb...

Comment: That one is indeed a bit harder to find, but the name should give a big clue. "verb     : level of verbosity, from 0 (almost mute) to 3 (verbose)" (https://fossies.org/dox/scapy-2.3.1/config_8py_source.html)

Comment: Whats is inter= 0.1 ?

Comment: @PaulSigonoso http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#send-and-receive-packets-sr `inter` is the time interval to wait between packets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About the code:

```
 ans,unans = srp(Ether(dst = "ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/ARP(pdst = ips), timeout = 2, iface = interface ,inter= 0.1)
```

What this code does is fairly simple. You use the srp funtion to send packets and receive answer for them - in this case that packets are constructed by the protocols: Ethernet and ARP. To understand what those protocols do and used for you must have some at least basic networking background. But anyway what this code does is asking the ip, specified by the pdst parameter, to tell its mac address.

In the tuple `ans,unans` parameter is stored the answer of the srp function.

Also, with the inter parameter you specify a time interval to wait between two packets.

As for the rcv.sprintf I didn't understood it either. You could possibly write something very simple like:

```
print rcv[ARP].psrc
print rcv[Ether].src
```

As for the **conf.verb=0** variable what it does is setting scapy's verbosity  to 0 so you don't get too much output in the terminal when you run the program.

Comment: @Paul Sigonoso , inter=0.1 is the rate packets/time ,simply you will have next packet in 0.1 sec .As for the second comment you have to read some practical books about network programming and for scapy basically.

Comment: @Paul Sigonoso, conf is not a file. conf has to do with every scapy session you are working with  and through that you can adjust some parameters like verbosity and many others. For example if you open up a terminal and write scapy then try to type conf and you will see a list of available options you can adjust. For more information take a look at:  http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/demo.html

Comment: Module can't teach you "what is ETH communication ?". Like this : `ETH buffer checking timer`, `Convert open-frame packets`, `Accessing level` etc.

Answer (score 1):

**1、Why there is a tuple ans,unans ?**

A: `srp` return `answered` and `unanswered` packets, so it is a tuple.[srp function](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/master/scapy/sendrecv.py)

**2、Whats is inter= 0.1 ?**

A: `inter` is a interval which resend unanswered packets or retry when no more packets are answered. `srp` function call `sndrcv`, the `inter` argument see [sndscv function](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/master/scapy/sendrecv.py)

**3、I didnt understand rcv.sprintf. What is this? Why rcv.sprintf instead of print?**

A:`sprintf` output str where format is a string that can include directives.A directive begins and
ends by % and has the following format `%[fmt[r],][cls[:nb].]field%`. The detail is here [sprintf function](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/master/scapy/packet.py).

**4、What is conf.verb = 0 ?**

A: 'conf.verb': level of verbosity, from 0 (almost mute) to 3 (verbose). [verb of Conf Class](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/master/scapy/config.py)